# Is it possible to change the logo/image on boot up? If so how?

Tags: boot, bios

For Example:

[image: The Lenovo boot up logo]
<sub>(source: [lenovo.com](http://download.lenovo.com/express/images/1-en-bootup_welcome_page.jpg))</sub>
;

Or is this simply ingrained in the system?

Comment: This completely depends on the Bios. It's always possible to do as the image has to be stored *somewhere* on your computer (unless they have a pre-installed font and output text, which is doubtful), however Bios related files are not always easily accessible. What is your computer model?

Comment: @Chipperyman I have a Lenovo Y510p running Windows 8.1 (x64)

Comment: A very few BIOSes explicitly allow you to change the image, otherwise it's hacking around in stuff you really don't want to be hacking around in.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bios setting not an OS setting. You should be able to disable it through the bios, but it depends on the bios if you can replace the image. I imagine that some bios' are that configurable but not most.